# How to reinit some values in session bean on page load?

Tags: jsf

i want to make something similar to view scope with the session scope.
i have a session bean, and in my page i have some search result tables, that i want to clear them and clear the input texts on page load, i can't change from session bean to request bean, and my only idea right now is to add a clear button on the page which it's action method would reset the tables and the input texts.

i am using **jsf 1.1**, please advise about best way to do that.

Comment: You simply can't. You must set your managed bean in request scope and save all the initialization data in session and reload it in the managed bean constructor and use some sort of flag to let your managed bean knows if it should pull the data from session or just to reload it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the request is a GET request (or, at least, not a POST request).

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

if ("GET".equals(request.getMethod())) {
    // ...
}
```

On JSF 1.2, you'd have used [`ResponseStatemanager#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/ResponseStateManager.html#isPostback%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) for this.
On JSF 2.x, you'd have used [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) for this.

You could perform this in a getter of a (hidden) output component.

---

A completely different alternative is to install [Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) and use `<t:saveState>` to simulate the JSF 2.x view scope on a request scoped bean.

Comment: where to put above code in my managed bean ? since init method and constructor will be invoked in first time creating the session.

Comment: That's already answered. *"You could perform this in a getter of a (hidden) output component."*